# MsgBox doesn't stop the code

Tags: vb.net, msgbox

I have an onChange TextBox event. When textlength is 22 then a msgbox should be shown
and a db connection should be established.

Unfortunately the msgbox is not appearing or is appearing and disappearing quite fast.

It shouldnt happen like this. Ive tried also using ApplicationModal but this didnt change the anything.

Sample code:

```
Private Sub txt_Auftrag_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txt_Auftrag.TextChanged

    If Len(txt_Auftrag.Text) = 22 Then 'txt_Auftrag.TextLength = 22 Then
        MsgBox("In der If", MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        var_Aufrag = Mid(txt_Auftrag.Text, 15, 8)


        '------------------------------------------SET dbConnection
        Dim myConn As SqlConnection
        Dim myCmdText As String

        Try
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
            myConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=dbadm;Password=pw")
            myConn.Open() 
            lbl_Auftrag_Value.Text = var_Aufrag
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
        Catch ex As Exception
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            MsgBox("Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden. Kontaktieren Sie den Administrator. Fehlerbeschreibung: " & ex.Message)
            var_Aufrag = Nothing
            txt_Auftrag.Text = Nothing

            Exit Sub
        End Try

        MsgBox("ConnGood")
```

Comment: While it's good to provide sample code, can you provide your *actual* code?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to check if the code in the `If txt_Something.Text Length = 22` is executed at all?

Comment: If Statement is executed the code is landing (right now) in the catch block. There is also a MsgBox which is executed this time...

Comment: As @overmind said, you need to post the actual code you're using.  We can all see typographic errors in your post that instantly tell us it won't even compile like that!
If you're 'landing' in the `Catch`, then what's the exception??

Comment: I used `If TextBoxName.Text.Length = 22 Then MsgBox("Hello", MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal) Else End If` and it worked fine for me. What happens when you are debugging?

Comment: meaning there's an error in your db connection which prevents the process to reach your messagebox call. Try debug your connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I am programming for an MDT device and was scanning barcodes with it. When typing in a text equal 22 signs the msgbox was appearing. when scanning a barcode the If statement started while my finger was on the scanbutton and through releasing it the msgbox was clicked. Anyhow very strange :)

Thx and bye

Comment: Proved it through placing another msgbox just after this one .. and the second one popsup just like it should.. I suppose I should use a thread or so...